# How can I prevent a custom block from rewriting HTML?

Tags: 8, blocks

I have a self-contained widget written by a third party that consists of HTML, JS, and CSS. I've dumped it into a custom block with Full HTML (and verified the Full HTML settings are loose enough that they shouldn't conflict with the markup). Also, I'm using CKEditor. When I save the custom block, it turns `<div class="bookwidget">` into `<div class="bookwidget">&nbsp;</div>` so that the widget doesn't even get an opportunity to render.

Is there a workaround for this? Is my only alternative to create a custom module?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to `Admin menu > Configuration > Content authoring > Text formats and editors` then edit yours (E.g. "basic html")

Down towards the bottom you should see an option: `Correct faulty and chopped off HTML` - uncheck that option and save.

Not sure why a widget would expect an un-closed `<div />` tag though.

Comment: That option is unchecked. There is a close div,  it's just after all the HTML/JS/CSS. But when the editor rewrites it, it removes the </div> at the end and sticks it at the top.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid creating a custom plugin, then I would try creating a new Text Format and remove all processing options and offer no WYSIWYG.

However, this block of code sounds problematic, and the WYSIWYG is not really intended to host full applications. I think you would end up with a more reliable, more secure, higher quality product if you created a custom block and integrated the JS and CSS as libraries. This is more in line with the way that Drupal is intended to operate and allows the markup and JS/CSS assets to properly participate in sanitization, caching, aggregation, etc...

Comment: I did try creating a custom text format which had no editor and didn't do anything to the HTML. The result wouldn't render the HTML. I'll look into creating a custom block. I just thought this could be so easy.